# Compiling for Windows NT using Visual Studio 2005

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2005, windows-nt

I need to create an executable for Windows NT ( yes, Windows NT still exists ). The problem that I have is that VS2005 uses CRT/MFC 8.0, therefore after running the application using the CRT 8.0 libraries I will get an error complaining that GetlongpathnameW doesn't exist on the target environment, which should be fixed by going back to MFC 7.1 CRT libraries.

I have the libraries that I acquired from somewhere else (mfc71.dll, msvcp71.dll, msvcr71.dll....) but how do I get VS to use those instead of the default ones (MFC80.dll....)?

Here is the link of a person with the similar problem:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b6027b6d-7e30-4b76-b92b-b19982a33dfc/the-procedure-entry-point-getlongpathnamew-could-not-be-located-in-the-dynamic-link-library?forum=vcgeneral

Thanks!

Comment: Windows NT hasn't had any security updates for a decade now, so I seriously hope you do not have this machine connected to the Internet.

Comment: No, it is not fortunately.